# With memory_order_relaxed how is total order of modification of an atomic variable assured on typical architectures?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, memory-barriers, memory-model, stdatomic

As I understand `memory_order_relaxed` is to avoid costly memory fences that may be needed with more constrained ordering on a particular architecture.
In that case how is total modification order for an atomic variable achieved on popular processors?

EDIT:

```
atomic<int> a;

void thread_proc()
{
    int b = a.load(memory_order_relaxed);
    int c = a.load(memory_order_relaxed);
    printf(“first value %d, second value %d\n, b, c);
}

int main()
{

    thread t1(thread_proc);
    thread t2(thread_proc);
    a.store(1, memory_order_relaxed);
    a.store(2, memory_order_relaxed);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

What will guarantee that the output won’t be:

```
first value 1, second value 2
first value 2, second value 1
```

?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place for this question.

Comment: None of the `memory_order`s change the possible behaviours of that snippet

Comment: @Caleth if you mean that in any case there won’t be output such as I suggested then I agree. But what assembly instructions will be used to guarantee that other than memory barriers?

Comment: @listerreg You really should move your edit to a new question.  The question as it is now, about specific code, is qualitatively very different from the original which mainly about how memory_order_relaxed should be interpreted.

Comment: @Chuu "_qualitatively very different from the original_" different how?

Answer (score 3):

Multi-processors often use the [MESI protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol) to ensure total store order on a location.  Information is transferred at cache-line granularity. The protocol ensures that before a processor modifies the contents of a cache line, all other processors relinquish their copy of the line, and must reload a copy of the modified line. Hence in the example where a processor writes x and then y to the same location, if any processor sees the write of x, it must have reloaded from the modified line, and must relinquish the line again before the writer writes y.

Comment: Yes, but doesn’t this solve the case where different processors are unaware of changes made by each other and thus get the notion of being first to modify a memory location (like in Peterson’s algorithm)? I was thinking rather about reordering of the loads from the same location as in the code above.

Comment: Wouldn't your argument also prove that all memory accesses are fully ordered?

Comment: @listerreg - the whole point of the MESI protocol is that they _are_ aware of each other, as stated in the second sentence of my answer.

Comment: @curiousguy - I've corrected my answer to say "total store order".  Yes, MESI allows loads to be unordered.  Furthermore, the argument applies only at the cache-line level.

Comment: @curiousguy: With just MESI, there *is* a global order for all stores to *all* locations that all threads can agree on.  (Not loads, only stores).  To violate that, you need the possibility of a store becoming visible to some cores before it becomes *globally* visible to all cores, e.g. PowerPC's store-forwarding of retired stores between SMT logical cores within a physical core.  See [Will two atomic writes to different locations in different threads always be seen in the same order by other threads?](//stackoverflow.com/a/50679223) - C++11 mo_relaxed does allow it, but most ISAs don't

Comment: @ArchD.Robison "_MESI allows loads to be unordered_" then what? What does it mean for devices (CPU or other processor) with access to a coherent cache?

Comment: @PeterCordes Can you model the store buffer as a minuscule local cache that has no coherence protocol?

Comment: @ArchD.Robison "_they are aware of each other_" What is aware of what? The cache? The speculative exec engine? The memory access unit?

Comment: @curiousguy: For x86, no; stores can only commit in program order, preserving StoreStore ordering.  For weakly-ordered ISAs, yes that model might sort of work, except that real implementations won't let a store stay "invisible" / non-coherent indefinitely.  However, store coalescing within the store buffer is a real thing so having a 2nd store to the same location end up committing at the same time, meaning the first store was never globally visible, is realistic.  There might be problems with that model I haven't thought of, and fences don't have to be as simple as draining it.

Comment: @curiousguy "they are aware of each other" -- I'm assuming a model where each processor has a private cache.  The processors are aware of each other's actions to degree sufficient to ensure that if two processors have the same line in a non-invalid state (i.e. not the I state), then the line is in the shared (S) state.  Snooping  the bus is a common way to implement this awareness.

Comment: @ArchD.Robison The word "snooping" seems to imply delayed reaction, not a globally synchronous system.

Comment: @Arch D. Robison is my grammar that bad? ;) I’ve understood you correctly but how MESI solves the problem with reordered loads? And btw, are you saying that with the real implementations it’s not possible that store is in the store buffer and another thread _is_ unaware of it (so it gets the notion that it is the first one to modify the same memory location)?

Comment: @curiousguy "Snooping" is a term of art.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol#Operation .  In snooping the processors (or more precisely the caches therein) are watching the bus and changing their MESI state when they see certain bus transactions.  Specific to the original question, if a cache line is in the Shared (S) state, and a processor needs to write to the line, a "Bus Upgrade" transaction is sent, and the other caches see that transaction and relinquish the line.  Then the processor can modify the line.

Comment: @listerreg You are right that MESI alone does not stop a processor from reordering loads to the same location.  There's an additional restriction that a processor must not reorder its loads from the _same_ location.  A processor with in-order execution of instructions won't do such reordering anyway.  I don't know how processors with out-of-order execution deal with this, but suspect they resolve it using the same mechanisms as when dealing with an intervening store from themselves.

Comment: @listerreg With respect to a race condition of processors A and B writing to the _same_ address in their respective store buffers, how would they know they were the first to modify the location?  Only by reading the location afterwards and seeing that the _other_ processor changed it.  They can't both see they were first, since MESI forces the line to be passed around for updates.

Comment: @ArchD.Robison "_MESI alone does not stop a processor from_" The cache system and its invariants do not stop the processor from trying anything in its speculations. The cache is the cache and does not constrain the processor.

Answer (score 1):

There is usually a specific set of assembly instructions that corresponds to operations on std::atomics, for example an atomic addition on x86 is `lock xadd`.

By specifying `memory order relaxed` you can conceptually think of it as telling the compiler "you must use this technique to increment the value, but I impose no other restrictions outside of the standard as-if optimisations rules on top of that".  So literally just replacing an `add` with an `lock xadd` is likely sufficient under a relaxed ordering constraint.

Also keep in mind 'memory_order_relaxed' specifies a minimum standard that the compiler has to respect.  Some intrinsics on some platforms will have implicit hardware barriers, which doesn't violate the constraint for being too constrained.

Comment: And if it isn’t sufficient? How can we avoid memory fences while forcing total ordering? Basically I’m asking what is the gain from using memory_order_relaxed on architecture with some kind of OoO execution? Wouldn’t we need there some king of barrier to enforce total modification order of a single atomic variable anyway? For example gcc on Intel puts the mfence after store even with memory_order_relaxed.

Comment: @listerreg You might not be able to avoid memory fences on a particular platform. In that case `memory_order_relaxed` is of no use. On other platforms you can.

Comment: @listerreg What compiler flags are you using?  Compiler explorer is generating explicit memory fences at -O0 but at -O1 and higher is using only `mov` as expected.  https://godbolt.org/z/vh-qCw

Comment: Should be noted that the current question is very different to the pre-edit question, which is why this answer does not fit.

Comment: x86 `lock add` (or `lock xadd` if the `fetch_add` return value is needed) is strong enough for seq_cst (if the compiler also blocks compile-time reordering).  The `lock` prefix is a full barrier.  This answer doesn't really answer the current question at all, but maybe you should edit it with a note that a changed question invalidated it.  Also, the current question is about pure stores, not RMWs.  Anyway, x86 is not a useful ISA to consider here, @listerreg: asm stores are release-stores, asm loads are acquire-loads.  (No LoadLoad or StoreStore reordering in HW).

Answer (score 0):

All atomic operations act in accord with [[intro.races]/14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.races#14):

> If an operation A that modifies an atomic object M happens before an operation B that modifies M, then A shall be earlier than B in the modification order of M.

The two stores from the main thread are required to happen in that order, since the two operations are [ordered within the same thread](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.races#10.1). Therefore, they cannot happen outside of that order. If someone sees the value 2 in the atomic, then the first thread must have executed past the point where the value was set to 1, per [[intro.races]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.races#4):

> All modifications to a particular atomic object M occur in some particular total order, called the modification order of M.

This of course only applies to atomic operations on a specific atomic object; ordering with respect to other things doesn't exist when using `relaxed` ordering (which is the point).

How does this get achieved on real machines? In whatever way the compiler sees fit to do so. The compiler could decide that, since you're overwriting the value of the variable you just set, then it can remove the first store per the as-if rule. Nobody ever seeing the value 1 is a perfectly legitimate implementation according to the C++ memory model.

But otherwise, the compiler is required to emit whatever is needed to make it work. Note that out-of-order processors aren't typically allowed to complete dependent operations out of order, so that's typically not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts in an inter thread communication:

- a core that can do loads and stores
- the memory system which consists of coherent caches

### The issue is the speculative execution in the CPU core.

A processor load and store unit **always need to compare addresses** in order to avoid reordering two writes to the same location (if it reorders writes at all) or to pre-fetch a stale value that has just been written to (when reads are done early, before previous writes).

Without that feature, any sequence of executable code would be at risk of having its memory accesses completely randomized, seeing values written by a following instruction, etc. All memory locations would be "renamed" in crazy ways *with no way for a program to refer to the same (originally named) location twice in a row*.

All programs would break.

On the other hand, memory locations in potentially running code can have two "names":

- the location that can hold a modifiable value, in L1d
- the location that can be decoded as executable code, in L1i

And these are not connected in any way until a special reload code instruction is performed, not only the L1i but also the instruction decoder can have in cache locations that are otherwise modifiable.

[Another complication is when two virtual addresses (used by speculative loads or stores) refer to the same physical addresses (aliasing): that's another conflict that needs to be dealt with.]

Summary: In most cases, a CPU will naturally to provide an order for accesses on each data memory location.

EDIT:

While a core needs to keep track of operations that invalidate speculative execution, mainly a write to a location later read by a speculative instruction. Reads don't conflict with each others and a CPU core might want to keep track of modification of cached memory after a speculative read (making reads happen visibly in advance) and *if reads can be executed out of order it's conceivable that a later read might be complete before an earlier read*; on why the system would begin a later read first, a possible cause would be if the address computation is easier and complete first.

So a system that can begin reads out of order and that would consider them completed as soon as a value is made available by the cache, and valid as long as no write by the same core ends up conflicting with either read, and does not monitor L1i cache invalidations caused by another CPU wanting to modify a close memory location (possible that one location), such sequence is possible:

- decompose the soon to be executed instructions into sequence A which is long a list of sequenced operations ending with a result in r1 and B a shorter sequence ending with a result in r2
- run both in parallel, with B producing a result earlier
- speculatively try `load (r2)`, noting that a write that address may invalidate the speculation (suppose the location is available in L1i)
- then another CPU annoys us stealing the cache line holding location of (r2)
- A completes making r1 value available and we can speculatively do `load (r1)` (which happens to be the same address as (r2)); which stalls until our cache gets back its cache line
- the value of the last done load can be different from the first

Neither speculations of A nor B invalided any memory location, as the system doesn't consider either the loss of cache line or the return of a different value by the last load to be an invalidation of a speculation (which would be easy to implement as we have all the information locally).

Here the system sees any read as non conflicting with any local operation that isn't a local write and the loads are done in an order depending on the complexity of A and B and not whichever comes first in program order (the description above doesn't even say that the program order was changed, just that it was ignored by speculation: I have never described which of the loads was first in the program).

So **for a relaxed atomic load, a special instruction would be needed on such system**.

### The cache system

Of course the cache system doesn't change orders of requests, as it works like a global random access system with temporary ownership by cores.

Comment: Before I delve into cache details: does that mean that the two consecutive loads in the code above cannot be reordered (in a fashion resulting in them being interleaved with the two stores)? I didn’t expect the stores to be reordered though.

Comment: Yes loads can potentially be "reordered" (one done in advance). I was about to add a note to that effect. But if another CPU clobbers the same cache line before the value is used, you can cancel the speculation. Of course it takes additional logic to be able to monitor that situation and not all CPU are doing it.

Comment: @listerreg I have added a discussion of out of order reads when conflict is with a write in another CPU.